# Describe a fast (polynomial time)algorithm who takes as input the elements $g^a,g^b$ and gives as output the element $g^{a \cdot b}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Let $q$ prime number, $G$ a cyclic group with order $q$ and $g \in G$. Suppose that you have an algorithm $A$ who takes input the element $g^a$ of $G$ and gives as output the element $g^{a^2}$. Describe a fast (polynomial time) algorithm who takes as input the elements $g^a, g^b$ and gives as output the element $g^{a \cdot b}$ (namely an algorithm that solves the problem Diffie-Hellman).
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: A loose hint: $(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2=2ab$...

Comment: i am confused on the algorithm.what i have to show as algorithm?

Comment: cross-posted [to crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27152/991) less than 2 minutes after it was asked here $\;$

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $g^q = 1$ (the neutral element), we have in general,

$$g^{ab} = g^{ab} 1 = g^{ab} g^{qab} = g^{ab (q+1)} = g^{2ab \frac {q+1} 2} = \big( g^{2ab} \big) ^{\frac {q+1} 2} = \big( g^{(a+b)^2 -a^2 -b^2} \big) ^{\frac {q+1} 2} =\big( A(g^{a+b}) A(g^a)^{-1} A(g^b)^{-1} \big) ^{\frac {q+1} 2} ,$$

the last expression being able to be implemented efficiently provided that multiplication in the group can be performed efficiently (and using [binary exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for the outer exponentiation). In order to compute the inverse, note that $x^{-1} = x^{q-1}$, therefore inversion can be performed by exponentiation.

To clarify, we first compute $g^{2ab}$ as indicated in a comment below your question, then we remove the $2$ from the exponent by "extracting a square root", which means raising to $\frac {q+1} 2$.

Comment: Note that $h^{-1} = h^{q-1}$, and so we don't need to spell out the requirement that we can perform inversion explicitly (because we can compute $h^{q-1}$, if a more efficient method isn't available..

Comment: @poncho: Indeed, you are right, thank you for the comment; I have included it in my answer.